# Execute particular code on confirmation of user but confirm box must be activate during the php code not onsubmit form

Tags: php, javascript

After validating user data from database I want to update some values in the Database using php code.

I have tried

```
var answer = confirm("Do you want to Checkout?");
if(answer==true)
{
<?php MY UPDATE COMMAND ?>
}
```

but update command execute even if answer==false

Please help me in solving my problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are solutions for you:

1st - **use AJAX**. As for example with help of jQuery:

```
if (confirm('Do you want to Checkout?')) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'logout.php'
  }).done(function(){
    // do something after php checkout, for example: go to home page
    window.location.href = '/';
  });
}
```

2nd - is to use links like this:

```
<a href="checkout.php"
   onclick="return confirm('Do you want to Checkout?')">
Checkout</a>
```

Comment: I am still unable to update database query on confirmation of user. Please elaborate a bit or give me example. The code I pasted above runs without any click on hyperlink or button.

Comment: you need to write your own code inside of _logout.php_ to get user logged out. currently you works with javascript and wants to call php inside of javascript - it's impossible. javascript - client side, php - server side. this is not possible for php to be interactive as you think it must

Comment: place your
<?php MY UPDATE COMMAND ?>
to _logout.php_

Answer (score 0):

That can't work because PHP executes on the server side, before any javascript is even sent to the browser. So what will happen is your `MY UPDATE COMMAND` will execute first, before the Javascript - which is executed client side in the browser.

If you want to execute some PHP if the confirm is true then you will need to submit a form, or do an AJAX call at that point. I suggest reading up on how PHP and Javascript execute.

Answer (score 0):

javascript is a client side program (in this case) which is ran within a clients browser.  Php is a Server side scripting language.  Basically php generates an html file and sends it to the client.  All php commands are executed before anything happens in javascript because php simply generates an html file.  The javascript is loaded in the clients browser.

So the php command will ALWAYS run because it is being called.  PHP has no idea that it is surrounded by javascript code and does nothing to read it.  It just includes the javascript code in the html file that it sends along.

Comment: [nitpick]JavaScript needn't be client side: things like node.js run server-side: [a list of server-side JS solutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_server-side_JavaScript_solutions). However, this case does imply client side JS, so your answer is correct[/nitpick]